# A problem occurs when the Pass package is added

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

When I add a pass package, `"92001 Signature Verification Error"` Is Displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the following steps:

1. Check whether the certificates and private keys in the three .properties files in the src\test\resources directory of the huaweipasssdk.rar package are replaced.
2. Check whether the value of passType used when the huaweipasssdk project is used to obtain the signature is the same as that registered with HUAWEI Developer.
3. Reconfigure the certificate and replace the original certificate. Check whether the error persists.